# Yum History and History Undo in Centos 6

Tags: centos, yum, repository

I have a Centos 6 server and I have upgraded several packages. I can, supposedly, downgrade them with `yum history undo <packageName>` but all I get is `downgrade failed` for every single package.

In the documentation it says that it downgrades if there is an older version in the repositories. So my question is: Which repositories? Obviously the ones I have, include the latest versions. How can I configure such a thing?

In my repolist the only repos enabled are:

```
Centos-6 - Base
Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 6 - x86_64
Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 6 - Testing - x86_64 - Source
CentOS-6 - Extras
CentOS-6 - Updates
```

Thank you

Comment: Those are the repositories.

Comment: But then why can't I undo? How come every downgrade fails?

Comment: Hm, then perhaps you should edit your question. We can't see your screen nor read your mind, so we don't know what you're seeing.

Comment: What additional information would you like. I would be happy to provide them. The issue is that when I do yum history undo #transID it doesn't undo the update.

Comment: You can copy and paste, right?

Answer (score 1):

## Note

`yum history undo` takes transaction id (not package name) as an argument and clearly communicates that to you if you get it wrong

```
Bad transaction ID given
Error: Failed history undo
```

but since you got `Failed to downgrade` message, I'm going to assume that's just a typo and you do have transaction id from `yum history list`.

## Answer

This is likely due to archive repository being disabled. For example, CentOS uses `CentOS-Vault.repo` to hold packages from previous releases while Webtatic uses `webtatic-archive.repo`.

To see all installed (not just enabled) repositories:

```
ls -la /etc/yum.repos.d/
```

Find appropriate `<archive_repository>.repo` for your failed package(s), set `enabled=1` and roll back your transaction:

```
yum history undo <transaction_id>
```

Comment: I don't have access to the server anymore. Thanks for taking the time to respond however. I will test this when I get the first opportunity and let you know how it went.